# Are enums allowed to have setters in Java?

Tags: java, enums

I have an `enum` and it has a parameter (field) that is a `String`.
Am I allowed to have a setter for this field?

```
public enum Blah {
    Monday("a"), Tuesday("b");
}

private final String letter;

Blah(String letter){
    this.letter = letter;
}
```

Am I allowed to do the following?

```
public String setLetter(String letter){
    this.letter = letter;
}
```

Comment: What programming language? Show us a representative example of the code you're referring to.

Comment: Are you using any particular programming language?

Comment: Why don't you open up your IDE and see if this compiles?

Comment: You are *allowed* to, but it somewhat ruins the point of it being an enum.  However, `letter` can't be declared as `final` if you wish to set its value more than once.

Comment: final variables cannot be overrriden as @Vulcan pointed out

Answer (score 11):

You need to remove the `final` modifier of the field in order for it to be settable:

```
public enum Blah {
    Monday("a"), Tuesday("b");


    private String letter;

    private Blah(String letter){
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public void setLetter(String letter){
        this.letter = letter;
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/QAZHol

Having mutable state in an enum is generally not recommended, however.

Answer (score 5):

Update: It's possible to have setters in enum types.

```
public class Main {

public enum Account {

    ACCOUNT("NAME");

    private String name;

    private Account(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Account.ACCOUNT.getName()); // print NAME
    Account.ACCOUNT.setName("NEW");
    System.out.println(Account.ACCOUNT.getName()); // print NEW
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't work because the field is marked as `final`.

In principle, there is nothing preventing enums from having mutable fields. However, this is rarely if ever a good idea.

Comment: And it is not a good idea because the value you set in the setter will be shared across all enum instances...

Comment: It's because there's only one instance per enum constant, so the value of the field is shared across all references to that instance.

Answer (score 2):

Allowed, but, if you are going to use the enum in multithreaded environment, please do not forget that although Java enum, effectively a **lazy-initialized singleton**, 
is guarded by Java during the lazy initialization 
(meaning here that no any other thread could access the enum until the initializing thread has not completed the initialization), 
it is **not anyhow guarded against a concurrent use of the setter**.

So, in the OP's case of simple setter it is enough to declare the mutable field as `volatile` (remove `final` of course):

```
volatile int letter;
```

In more complex cases like increments or others (highly unlikely with enums, but ... who knows, enum setter is itself an exotic thing) other concurrency weaponry like `Atomic`s, `synchronized` blocks, `Lock`s might be needed.

Also, there is [a discussion on enum thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531873/how-thread-safe-is-enum-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

During using `Enums` it's always a good idea to declare variables as `final`.
Since it is not done in the above example we are able to set the value to something else.

By definition:
`Enums` are just like any other class, with a predefined **NonChanging/FIXED** set of instances.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EnumExample {
        public enum Blah {
        Monday("a"), Tuesday("b");


        private String letter;

        private Blah(String letter){
            this.letter = letter;
        }

        public void setLetter(String letter){
            this.letter = letter;
        }

        public String getLetter(){
             return letter;
        }
    }

        public static void main (String[] args)         {
             System.out.println("The Value of Monday is "+ Blah.Monday.getLetter());//prints a
             System.out.println("The Value of Tuesday is "+Blah.Tuesday.getLetter());//prints b
        }
}
```